# How to create various types of faults automatically in power transmission lines by using Fault Generator Component in MATLAB/Simulink

Tags: matlab, fault

I am creating a database of different types of faults that occur in power transmission lines using MATLAB/Simulink. I can simulate all types of faults by using Fault Component given in Simulink Component Library. I need thousands of faults of faults for my research work and every time I have to record simulation results in a table. Anyone please, is there is any way to generate specific type of fault repeatedly but with different sets of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible through MATLAB scripts. Simulink models can be run, controlled through scripts in MATLAB which offer more flexibility and control.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).